# Taking out bitcoin from offline wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, offline

Ok, let's say I have an offline wallet for storing my bitcoin, now I have got a good amount of bitcoin, but i don't want to take out everything from the wallet, I only want to take out a small amount, is that possible?

Comment: What sort of offline wallet? This is important to know, for example if you are using a paper wallet then the procedure to safely spend will be very different than the procedure for a hardware wallet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bitcoin is divisible to the 0.00000001 bitcoin, we call this small amount the "Satoshi" for example so even if you got less than 1 bitcoin you have a pretty wide margin on what amount you want to transfer it could be 200.0099 or 0.0005123 be careful of the fees though

For the transfer part I suggest you to use [electrum](https://electrum.org/#home)

You will find more useful information about the transfer from cold to online wallet there: [Can I spend/transfer bitcoins directly from cold storage?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/can-i-spend-transfer-bitcoins-directly-from-cold-storage?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Basically any bitcoin wallet application should allow you to choose exactly how much to send to another address.

Comment: Note: sending a transaction that doesn't spend the entire offline wallet's balance will most likely create a change address. It is VERY important to understand how a change address works, for example if OP has a paper wallet and spends only part of the balance, the remaining balance will no longer be stored at the paper wallet's address. This can (and has) lead to a loss of funds for users in the past.

Comment: care to explain? let's say I have got 10 bitcoins on a paper wallet, now i only want to take out 1 bitcoin, you mean the remaining 9 will be changed to another address?

Comment: @oliber yes (but that also depends on how many UTXOs represent those 10 BTC). Each UTXO must be spent in it's entirety, so the remainder will be sent to a new address you control (a 'change address'). Generally, whatever software you use to send craft and send the transaction will automatically create a change address for you (but it will not be the paper wallet address! It will be a new one). See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction

Comment: yes that's a good point about paper wallets. When @oliber said 'offline wallet', I assumed it was a hardware wallet, in which case the wallet would take care of the change address.

Comment: @chytrik, realistically if you want to send from a paper wallet, you'll use an app which imports your private key from the paper wallet, then creates, signs, and broadcasts your transaction for you. The app will most likely make a 'change' address for your 9 bitcoins. If you want to store those 9 bitcoins in another paper wallet, you should get the app to send it to that new paper wallet. You could re-use the old paper wallet although it's a bit less secure (realistically probably secure enough though) and makes your transactions easier to track.

Comment: @Darius yes, but if you don’t realize that the wallet app has sent your change to a new address, and you remove that app from your computer (thinking the remainder is still on the paper wallet), then your change will be lost. This has happened to many users in the past, hence my comments.